# Android Simulator does not show the interface properly

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using AVD Manager to run Android Simulator on my labtop. I can run the simulator but the interface of mobile in the simulator is not usable and I can not use it at all,  I attached how it looks and what is the simulator setting.

[image: Simulator interface for Nexus 5, Platform 7]

[image: Interface setting]

Comment: Your CPU/ABI of "Android TV Intel Atom" is only a good choice if you are trying to develop for a TV, and it may be contributing to your problem. Beyond that, switch the Skin to "No Skin" and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, finally I changed the CPU and Skin, and one of them works! thanks.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use genymotion instead of android simulator because android simulator is very slow. You will feel too good after using genymotion. Just give a try to it.